# Can't compile std::list iterator with template

Tags: c++, stl

When I try to compile this I get this error:

```
error: expected `;' before 'it'
```

Why I can't declare this iterator? Where is the problem?

```
#include <list>

template <typename Z>
class LBFuncBase: public LBBaseBlock<Z>
{
    void Something() {
         std::list<LBBaseBlock< Z >* >::iterator it;
    }
};
```

Comment: The semicolon for finishing the class declaration?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
typename std::list<LBBaseBlock< Z >* >::iterator it;
```

Edit:

See "[Why do you sometimes need to write typename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247555/why-do-you-sometimes-need-to-write-typename-t-instead-of-just-t/1247563#1247563)" for an explanation.

Comment: Lucky me, I'm usually at least 7 seconds late :).